# Is there a way to call an api directly in fastapi whenever backend server starts?

Tags: api, fastapi, starlette

So i have an API which updates weather data in db every hour(using repeat_every decorator). Is there a way to call this API automatically whenever back-end server is up and running instead of manually calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. You can define **event handlers** *(functions)* that need to be executed before the application starts up and shutting down.

You can use **`@app.on_event("startup" | "shutdown")`**

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    do something...


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    do something...
```

If you are encountring circular import Error, create your api as router than import from your main file.

Example

```
from fastapi import APIRouter


router = APIRouter()

@router.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    do something...
```

And from your main file

```
from path_to_your_api import router

app.include_router(router)
```

Comment: I have created app object in main.py file and when importing this 'app' in api file and doing the same, it is throwing a circular import errror.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar if you think problem isn't resolved update the question or gimme more details.

Comment: @Yagzican So i have on_startup event handler for my mongodb connection in main.py file also. So with the above suggestion api is getting called but not able to connect to db.

Comment: This wasn't the question, this is completely a different case,but i already know why you are encountering the problem, ask a new one with including the details, so i can help.

Comment: @Yagzican Can you please help me out in this space only?

Comment: Nope, stackoverflow guidelines against that, the problem should focus on one problem only.